# Weird cancel icon keeps popping up?

Tags: icons, gnome-shell

This icon continually pops up when I'm using my computer no matter what I'm doing.

[image: This is the icon in question.]

I'm on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 and it's really bothering me as it wasn't an issue when I was running Kubuntu at all. It creates errors with typing and whenever it happens I have to tab out and back into the window I was in before I can continue my task, otherwise no keystrokes or mouse-clicks will work.

Any idea?

Comment: That's probably a hardware problem. The icon appears when some kind of media button is pressed and the associated action is not permitted/supported. This in turn means that the desktop environment receives key presses that you didn't initiate, so your keyboard is probably faulty. You can try to debug the issue by running `xev` and looking at the key events when the icon comes up.